# solr, find documents containing a similar query word

Tags: solr, spell-checking

Could you please give me some advice about how to search documents with text where a word is *similar* to a given one.

For instance, a document contains the word *house* and the word in query is *huse*.

Other valid examples:

- randomize for the query ranmize.
- looky for the query looqui.

It's not about fuzzy search but a little bit more *smart*.  Spellchecking with maxEdits=2 it's not sufficient.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it kind-of-is the definition of fuzzy search with `~<factor>`. Another option is phonetic search if you're looking for something which sounds similar, without being written similar. But be wary of false positives.

Comment: Probably Multilingual Search or Synonyms are an option for you? But that depends on what you try to achieve.